# Add driver to service (DI container by SpecFlow.DependencyInjection) at BeforeScenario attribute hooks

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, dependency-injection, automated-tests, specflow

I am using [SpecFlow.DependencyInjection](https://github.com/solidtoken/SpecFlow.DependencyInjection)

I created and added service at ScenarioDependencies attribute like this

```
[ScenarioDependencies]
public static IServiceCollection CreateServices()
{
    var services = new ServiceCollection();

    // Add various stuffs here

    return services;
}
```

The problem is that method (CreateServices) run before BeforeScenario attribute, and I am also using this lib: [SpecFlow.Contrib.Variants](https://github.com/totaltest/SpecFlow.Contrib.Variants) allow me to choose which driver I want to use.

Usually at BeforeScenario hooks, I write the code like

```
[BeforeScenario]
public void BeforeScenario()
{
    _scenarioContext.TryGetValue("Browser", out var browser);

    switch (browser)
    {
        case "Chrome":
            _driver = SetupChromeDriver();
            break;
        case "Firefox":
            _driver = SetupFirefoxDriver();
            break;
        default:
            _driver = SetupChromeDriver();
            break;
    }
    _scenarioContext.ScenarioContainer.RegisterInstanceAs(_driver);
}
```

But using Solidtoken/SpecFlow.DependencyInjection make `_scenarioContext.ScenarioContainer.RegisterInstanceAs` not working anymore, and I have no way to register it to the service in CreateServices() method.

How I can reigster a driver to DI container?

I am hoping can catch it in constructor for using later
Like

```
public void DoSomething(IWebDriver driver)
{
    _driver = driver
    // use driver do something else
}
```

Comment: Why do you even need a ServicesCollection object? Why now just use the scenario container like before? The scenario container is a DI container.

Comment: I know about that, but my boss want (force) me to use Microsoft DI instead of Bodi (the default scenario container). I am a slave and can't argue about it u know .~.

Comment: Why not register the driver in your ScenarioDependencies hook?

Comment: More specifically, why not register the web driver in the `IServicesCollection` inside your `[ScenarioDependencies]` hook?